# fidling with hibernation slowness on XP needed

Tags: windows-xp, regedit, hibernation

Hibernating my laptop is very slow: 30min +, I have googled to no avail helas. some conflicting info and voodoo fidling seems to help some but not others (ie disabling DMA cache on the drive)

My particular setup is as follows
acer travelmate 663LMi , XP pro SP2, all other updates installed
main system drive has  C: partition with system  and a few other partitions, (physical and logical)

In my registry 
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management"
has var name "PagingFiles" with value 
"F:\pagefile.sys 1000 3000"
F: being the second partition, nevertheless hiberfil.sys is created in c:\ root

I find no entry for hiberfil.sys in the registry tho, is it a problem?
I am sure i didnt change pertinent registry entries.

One suggestion is to put a new path in another partition of the main hard drive (where C: system resides). Some people strongly advise against that.

Another advice i saw was to enabe “write caching”  but some people report no change to slow hibernation problem with this.
A relevent  question I have is if the write caching setting applies to ALL partition in the same drive, and not ala cart, ie each partition can have differnet setting?
I am a bit worried using my laptop's system partition with enabed “write caching”, shouldn't I be? My initial thougth was to move all pagefile hiberfils to a empty partition 
with enabed “write caching” if necessary and if possible to keep system partition disabled “write caching”.

Before I start fidling with the registry on my work laptop I would really appreciate some relevent and tried advice/info to understand the problem.

It might be pertinent a blinking light on the front panel left to the battery led light.
Another culprit might be external usb HD, USB hub, (??!usb mouse & keybord)? ethernet cable connected?! making the laptop to wait for some powerdown that never comes?

Thanx in advance

gio

ps just found this entry too
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
has var name HibernationPreviouslyEnabled with value "1"

Comment: This post really belongs in SuperUser or ServerFault forums

Answer (score 0):

When your machine goes into hibernation, windows attempts to write running file/application data to your RAM for temporary storage. Slowness in hibernation can be from a few different factors, but the main ones I've seen is the user having too many files or applications open when the machine goes into hibernation, and/or the machine has very little RAM to temporarily store this information.

Answer (score -1):

eh Mechaflash? Hibernation involves writing the RAM to a hibernation file on disk not saving running programs to ram